# cURL downloading images of camera (http request)

Tags: c++, image, curl, camera

I have installed cURL, and I was able to download an image from website, and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </usr/include/curl/curl.h>
#include </usr/include/curl/stdcheaders.h>
#include </usr/include/curl/easy.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
   size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
   return written;
}

int main(void) {
   CURL *curl;
   FILE *fp;
   CURLcode res;

   char *url = "http://www.example.com/test_img.png"; 
   char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/home/c++_proj/output/web_req_img.png";
   curl = curl_easy_init();
   if (curl) {
       fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       /* always cleanup */
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
       fclose(fp);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I also have a dlink DCS-930L camera. I can easily connect my camera a static IP address, and I was able to view live video on the camera, by logging into the camera (e.g. `http://192.168.1.5`).
I don't need any special software or anything to start watch video.

Now, I would like to use cURL to download images from camera. But I am not sure how to do it.
Could someone please tell me, or provide some piece of code for it?
All I want to do is to capture (sample) few of the images that are being streamed.
How do I know when to make a request, and when would be the boundary between the images.

I would truly appreciate some advise and piece of code that could get me going.

T

Comment: That depends entirely on the interface provided by the camera, i.e. what the content type of the images/video being displayed on `http://192.168.1.5` actually is. The only people that will be able to help you are those who have that exact camera at home.

Comment: @Ruby: Please avoid using signature while posting the Question mate, Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual for this camera [1], you need use a Java or ActiveX plugin to receive and watch the video:

> Please make sure that you have the latest version of Java application
>   installed on your computer to ensure proper operation when viewing the
>   video in Java mode. The Java application can be downloaded at no cost
>   from Sun’s web site (http://www.java.com).
>
> When you connect to the home page of your camera, you will be prompted
>   to download ActiveX. If you want to use ActiveX to view your video
>   images instead of Java, then you must download ActiveX.

This suggests that grabbing the image is going to be more difficult than simply making an HTTP request.

```
[1] http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/-/media/Consumer_Products/DCS/DCS%20930L/Manual/DCS%20930L_Manual_EN_US.pdf
```

Comment: The reason I want to grab the image, is because I want to do some image processing on it. So, somehow I would need to download images so that I can bring it into a programming language. Can I do it somehow with either C/C++/Python/Java program?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this camera, so I don't know. Look at the source of the webpage with the plugin, and maybe try sniffing the network traffic - maybe it's just a stream of JPGs, which you then could intercept and save.